# How to convert code from program to class (Getters and setter)

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm trying to create a card game which would generate a random card from a different class. The problem is that the block of code dedicated for the random card is big. Is there a way to transfer this part of the code to my Card class and use getters and setters to use in the main program? Or is there a way to make the code for generating random card more simple?

Main program:

```
String NewCard = "";
int theSuit, theRank;

for(int i=0; i<1; i++) { 
theRank= (int)(Math.random()*13);
theSuit = (int)(Math.random()*5);

clsCard cardFace = new clsCard( theSuit, theRank);

NewCard =cardFace.toString();
System.out.println(" Your new card  is " + NewCard);
```

Card Class:

```
public class clsCard {

    private int value;
    private int rank, suit;
    private final int MaxFaceValue= 10;
    private static String[] suits = {"Joker","hearts","spades","diamond","clubs"};
    private static String[] ranks = {"Joker","Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};

    public clsCard(int suit, int rank)
    {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    public @Override String toString()
    {
        if(ranks[rank].equals("Joker") || suits[suit].equals("Joker"))
            return "Joker";
        else
            return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }

    public int getRank()
    {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `java` !== `javascript`

Comment: I'm not sure about anyone else, but I'm not clear on exactly what it is you're asking here. If possible, please be more specific with your question, including showing your own attempt to solve whatever problem it is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: This `System.out.println(" Your new card  is " + NewCard);` should instead be simply `System.out.println(" Your new card  is " + cardFace);`. The println method will call the object's `toString()` method automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a constructor that generates the random value

```
 public clsCard() {
    this.rank= (int)(Math.random()*ranks.length);
    this.suit= (int)(Math.random()*suits.length);
}
```

Make `new clsCard()` in the other class

You can also make some `public static List<clsCard> generateCards(int amount)` method to not pollute your main method.

Then you can do

```
for (clsCard c : clsCard.generateCards(1)) {
    System.out.println(" Your new card  is " + c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!! This is what I been looking for. BUT :) (I'm new to Java) When I type the second part "for (clscard..." in my main class text is underlined and says "the method generateCards(int) is undefined for the type clscard" (I'm programming in java eclipse.)

Comment: 1) Don't copy code you don't understand 2) I said you could define the method. I didn't show you how

Comment: So can you show me how to define it and explain. Pleaseee :) - I'm trying to make this program since this morning :)

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a coding service, so try something on your own. (Eclipse even will autocomplete the method definition for you). If you're stuck, you can post a new question, not a comment

Answer (score 3):

Folks are telling you to give your Card a constructor that generates a random Card, and I disagree. If this is your goal, to select a random card, and if your goal is to have your code mirror reality, then to solve this properly, you need another class, a `Deck` class, one that holds a collection of cards, probably a `List<Card>` that is an `ArrayList<>`. Then you can *shuffle* the deck (its collection) by calling `Collections.shuffle(cardList);`, and extract shuffled cards from the ArrayList by calling its `.remove(0)` method, one that removes the first Card from the collection and returns it.

Note also that this type of program is often used in tutorials on how and where to use enums, since the card's suit and rank (or value) are well suited to being enums. For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CardFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(deck.deal());
        }
    }
}
```

```
enum Rank {
    JOKER(0), ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
    TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13);
    private int value;

    private Rank(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

```
enum Suit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES  
}
```

```
class Card {
    private Suit suit;
    private Rank rank;
    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (rank == Rank.JOKER) {
            return "joker";
        } 
        return "" + rank + " of " + suit;            
    }

    // equals and hashCode    
}
```

```
class Deck {
    private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Deck() {
        regenerate();
    }

    final public void regenerate() {
        cardList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < Rank.values().length; i++) {
                Rank rank = Rank.values()[i];
                Card card = new Card(suit, rank);
                cardList.add(card);
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cardList);
    }

    public Card deal() {
        if (cardList.size() == 0) {
            // throw an exception
        }
        return cardList.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree overall, the question simply asked how to "clean" the shown code

Comment: @cricket_007: Understood, and it's totally up to the OP to decide which answer best services his purpose, but to me it's like nails grating on a chalkboard to see the Card class do things that it really shouldn't be doing. Cheers.

Comment: @cricket_007: but one plus for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

You could decide that a constructor without parameters for `clsCard` would randomly generate the values, the using it:

```
public clsCard() {
    this.suit = (int)(Math.random() * suits.length);
    this.rank = (int)(Math.random() * ranks.length);
}
```

But this seems a bit arbitrary.

You could also create a `static` method in `clsCard` for generating random instances.

```
public static clsCard generateRandomCard() {
    return new clsCard((int)(Math.random() * suits.length), 
                       (int)(Math.random() * ranks.length));
}
```

By the way, a comment irrelevant to your question: Your method of generating a random card doesn't really makes 1 out of 52 for each card (Jokers will appear much more frequently). If that's important, you might want to think about that.

Comment: The first code block seems to be perfect! But how would I use it in my main class. for (clsCard c : clsCard(1)) { System.out.println(" Your new card  is " + c); } ?

Comment: No. `clsCard(1)` would be expected to be a collection, but it's actually meaningless as `clsCard` doesn't have a constructor that expects one parameter. Use `clsCard cardFace = new clsCard();` instead.